# Adding a parcel repository using Cloudera Manager Python API

Tags: python, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to install CDH5 parcels on Hadoop-cluster using [Cloudera Manager Python API](http://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/docs/python-client/). I'm doing this using following code:

```
test_cluster = ... # configuring cluster
# adding hosts ...
for parcel in test_cluster.get_all_parcels():
    if parcel.product == 'CDH' and 'cdh5':
        parcel.start_download().wait()
        parcel.start_distribution().wait()
        success = parcel.activate().wait().success
```

But I catch such error:

```
cm_api.api_client.ApiException: Parcel for CDH : 5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42 is not available on UBUNTU_TRUSTY. (error 400)
```

The `CDH 5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42` was in `AVAILABLE_REMOTELY`, as we can see if print a string representation on this parcel:

```
<ApiParcel>: CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42 (stage: AVAILABLE_REMOTELY) (state: None) (cluster: TestCluster)
```

After the execution of code, parcel changes its stage to `DOWNLOADED`.

It seems, I should add a new parcel repository, compatible with Ubuntu Trusty (14.04). But I don't know of doing this using Cloudera Manager API.

**How I can specify the new repository for installing correct CDH?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to be more specific about the parcel you are acting on.  I use something like this for the same purpose, the important part for your question is the combined check on `parcel.version` and `parcel.product`. After that (yes I am verbose in my output) I print the list of parcels to verify I am trying to only install the 1 parcel I want.

I'm sure you've been here, but if not the [cm_api github site](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/docs/python-client/#managing-parcels) has some helpful examples too.

```
cdh_version = "CDH5"
cdh_version_number = "5.6.0"
# CREATE THE LIST OF PARCELS TO BE INSTALLED (CDH)
parcels_list = []
for parcel in cluster.get_all_parcels():
    if parcel.version.startswith(cdh_version_number) and parcel.product == "CDH":
        parcels_list.append(parcel)

for parcel in parcels_list:
    print "WILL INSTALL " + parcel.product + ' ' + parcel.version

# DISTRIBUTE THE PARCELS
print "DISTRIBUTING PARCELS..."
for p in parcels_list:
    cmd = p.start_distribution()
    if not cmd.success:
        print "PARCEL DISTRIBUTION FAILED"
        exit(1)
# MAKE SURE THE DISTRIBUTION FINISHES
for p in parcels_list:
    while p.stage != "DISTRIBUTED":
        sleep(5)
        p = get_parcel(api, p.product, p.version, cluster_name)
    print p.product + ' ' + p.version + " DISTRIBUTED"

# ACTIVATE THE PARCELS
for p in parcels_list:
    cmd = p.activate()
    if not cmd.success:
        print "PARCEL ACTIVATION FAILED"
        exit(1)
# MAKE SURE THE ACTIVATION FINISHES
for p in parcels_list:
    while p.stage != "ACTIVATED":
        p = get_parcel(api, p.product, p.version, cluster_name)
    print p.product + ' ' + p.version + " ACTIVATED"
```